# Correct syntax for "must not" search rule on Laravel Scout Elasticsearch "babenkoivan/scout-elasticsearch-driver" package

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-scout

I am trying to add a `must_not` clause to my search using Laravel Scout and `babenkoivan/scout-elasticsearch-driver` on top of Elasticsearch.

The idea is to exclude all results where the `sold` field either has a timestamp of more than 14 days, or is greater than zero.

I can't seem to get the correct syntax however, and there is no documentation on how to do this on the package repo. I tried formatting it like it is in the Elasticsearch docs but this is not correct.

Here is the set of rules:

```
public function buildQueryPayload()
    {
        $query = $this->builder->query;

        return [
            'must' => [
                'query_string' => [
                    'query' => $query,
                ],
            ],
            'must_not' => [
                'term' => [
                    'visible' => 0
                ],
                'range' => [
                    'sold' => [
                        'lte' => time() - 1209601, // 14 days ago plus 1 second
                        'gte' => 0
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'should' => [
                ...
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Currently I get a `Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception` error.

Here is the error complaining about the syntax:

```
{
   "error":{
      "root_cause":[
         {
            "type":"parsing_exception",
            "reason":"[term] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
            "line":1,
            "col":97
         }
      ],
      "type":"parsing_exception",
      "reason":"[term] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
      "line":1,
      "col":97
   },
   "status":400
}
```

Any ideas so we can get this documented for posterity? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing 'term' with 'match'.